# Is it possible to program an atmega32 via internet or remotely with Android app?

Tags: programming, remote-control, atmega32u4

There is a board with `atmega32` microcontroller, sim card and Bluetooth modules. I used to program this microcontroller using a serial port cable. As long as the circuit is able to connect to internet, is it possible to program `atmega32` via internet remotely?

Comment: if you can use a SD bootloader and SD card, it could download the update binary to SD card and reset. but it is very possible that you don't have enough memory left for the SD library

Comment: @Juraj Could you please explain it a bit more, if you had the same experience?

Comment: I enhanced the Arduino OTA library for SAMD to support classic ATmega Arduinos with at least 64 kB of flash. there are two ways: storing the uploaded update in upper half of the flash or on SD card. with less then 64 kB of flash there is no space for networking library + flash space or networking library + SD library. but maybe you can fit it with download over cellular network or bluetooth. https://github.com/jandrassy/ArduinoOTA/blob/master/examples/Advanced/OTASketchDownload_SD/OTASketchDownload_SD.ino